# JsonObjectRequest não entra no onResponse()

Tags: android, json, request

Estou fazendo um projeto de automação residencial com *Android* e *Arduino* e tenho esse trecho de código na minha classe cujo objetivo é consultar os valores do WebService em Json.
Mas toda vez que chamo esse método ele não entra dentro do **OnResponse()**, ele pula direto para o final, no **queue.add(getRequest)**.

A URL está certa e as tags também.

```
 public void lerLuminosidade(Context contexto) {
    String IP = URL_LER;

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(contexto);

    JsonObjectRequest getRequest =
            new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, IP, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    try {
                        if (jsonObject.has("luminosidadeSala")) {
                            luminosidade[0] = jsonObject.getString("luminosidadeSala");
                        }
                        if (jsonObject.has("luminosidadeQuarto")) {
                            luminosidade[1] = jsonObject.getString("luminosidadeQuarto");
                        }
                        if (jsonObject.has("luminosidadeGaragem")) {
                            luminosidade[2] = jsonObject.getString("luminosidadeGaragem");
                        }
                        if (jsonObject.has("luminosidadeCozinha")) {
                            luminosidade[3] = jsonObject.getString("luminosidadeCozinha");
                        }
                        if (jsonObject.has("fanSala")){
                            ventilador[0] = jsonObject.getString("fanSala");
                        }
                        if (jsonObject.has("portaoGaragem")) {
                            int portao = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("portaoGaragem"));
                            if (portao >= 1) {
                                statusPortao = true;
                                portaoGaragem[0] = "1";
                            }
                            else {
                                statusPortao = false;
                                portaoGaragem[0] = "0";
                            }
                            if (portao == 0) {
                                statusPortao = false;
                                portaoGaragem[0] = "0";
                            }
                        }

                        Log.d("Resposta: ", jsonObject.toString());

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("Error", "Não foi possível acessar: " + URL_LER);

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.d("Error.Response", volleyError.getMessage());

                }
            });
    queue.add(getRequest);

}
```

Comment: A requisição primeiro entra na fila (queue.add) e só depois que o seu listener é executado. Olha o seu log, que com certeza você tem as informações lá.

Answer (score 1):

Cara,
Primeiro de tudo: esse código está mega confuso. 
Voce esta montando uma instancia do objeto JsonObjectRequest passando no ultimo parâmetro um listener - que é uma classe que tem um comportamento que é onde você que debugar.

No entando, em nenhum momento você deixa EXPLICITO que o getRequest tem que executar o Response.Listener.. pra piorar a situação você delega a execução para uma fila, quando chama o método queue.add(getRequest);

Pra ficar um cadinho pior, você também não está executando nada na fila...

Você construiu uma hierarquia de execuções instanciado classes passando-as como parâmetros de outras classes e não deu o comando de execução inicial....

Esse não é código linear, embora a escrita seja...

Vai na documentação do Volley....

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.